# Update statement failing in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Below update statement is giving me error, please correct me where I am going wrong

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near i
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near u

Code:

```
Update [dbo].[ManPlan_Prescriber_Roster] i  
set i.territory_no = u.territory_no,  
    i.key_sales_force = u.key_sales_force,  
    i.territory_type_id = u.territory_type_id,  
    i.territory_type_descr = u.territory_type_descr,  
    i.last_name = u.last_name,  
    i.first_name = u.first_name,  
    i.mi = u.mi,  
    i.territory_orig_assign_dt = u.territory_orig_assign_dt,  
    i.territory_strt_dt = u.territory_strt_dt,  
    i.email_address = u.email_address,  
    i.cell_phone = u.cell_phone,  
    i.fcl_addr1 = u.fcl_addr1,  
    i.fcl_city = u.fcl_city,  
    i.fcl_st = u.fcl_st,  
    i.fcl_zip = u.fcl_zip  
from 
    [dbo].[ManPlan_Prescriber_Roster] m  
join 
    (select 
         territory_no,  
         key_sales_force,  
         territory_type_id,  
         territory_type_descr,  
         last_name,  
         first_name,  
         mi,  
         territory_orig_assign_dt,  
         territory_strt_dt,  
         email_address,  
         cell_phone,  
         fcl_addr1,  
         fcl_city,  
         fcl_st,  
         fcl_zip 
     from 
         [dbo].[RepRosterUpd$]  
     where 
         filedt = '2016-05-18') u on m.territory_no = u.territory_no 
                                  and m.key_sales_force = u.key_sales_force
                                  and m.territory_type_id = u.territory_type_id
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use the table you want to update in the `from` clause and give it an alias there (here: `m`), then you **must use** that alias in your `UPDATE` statement, too: `UPDATE m SET .....` - you cannot "redefine" the table with another alias at the top of your `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Also not seeing anything actually aliased as `u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the table you want to update in the `from` clause and give it an alias there (here: `m`), then you **must use** that alias in your `UPDATE` statement, too: `UPDATE m SET .....` - you cannot "redefine" the table with another alias at the top of your `UPDATE` statement

Try this:

```
Update m              // use the alias you've defined on the FROM line!
set m.territory_no = u.territory_no,  
    m.key_sales_force = u.key_sales_force,  
    ......
    m.fcl_zip = u.fcl_zip  
from 
    [dbo].[ManPlan_Prescriber_Roster] m   // use this alias in UPDATE 
join 
    (select 
         territory_no,  
         key_sales_force,  
         .....
         fcl_zip 
     from 
         [dbo].[RepRosterUpd$]  
     where 
         filedt = '2016-05-18') u on m.territory_no = u.territory_no 
                                  and m.key_sales_force = u.key_sales_force
                                  and m.territory_type_id = u.territory_type_id
```

Comment: @XYZ if his answer helps, please accept it as the answer. Thanks. :)